# How can I add a classpath entry as a publish/export dependency in an Eclipse dynamic web project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I successfully created a project using [Wicket quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) and turned it into an Eclipse dynamic web project by running

> mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

I imported the project to Eclipse without any issues, but got this warning for each JAR:

> Classpath entry M2_REPO/****.jar will not be exported or published.
>   Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.

I can fix this by using `right click → QuickFix` on each warning and selecting "Mark the associated raw classpath entry as a publish/export dependency," but this takes a lot of time and would not be possible if there were a lot of dependencies.

There must be a way to have Maven do this for me; what is it?

EDIT: I've found out that using [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) core + Maven Integration for WTP (from m2eclipse extras) resolves my issues.

I'm still interested in how to achieve this without m2eclipse, though, just out of curiosity :p

Comment: Are you using the m2eclipse plugin?

Comment: @artbristol I tried it both with and without m2eclipse. I only had m2eclipse-core installed, found out just a minute ago that installing 'Maven Integration for WTP' from m2eclipse extras resolves my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two Maven plugins needed to work with web projects in Eclipse are available from the Eclipse Marketplace.

[Maven Integration for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse) (included in the Java version of Eclipse)

[Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-wtp)