# Maven project in eclipse - deployment assembly fails build

Tags: eclipse, deployment, maven

Sorry for being verbose...

I have some existing maven projects. I imported them into Eclipse using *Maven -> Import existing Maven projects.*

This gave me 6 individual projects and one project which lists all  6 under it. (The umbrella project has 6 modules defined in it which translated to 6 eclipse project - as I understand how maven works)

One of the project A requires two other project B and C (at compile time and run-time).

Build path -
On the build path of A I have one of the libraries as Maven dependencies. And it builds fine.

Deployment assembly -
On the deployment assembly of A however there is no entry for deploy to `web-inf/lib`. Because of that when tomcat starts it doesn't find any required jars or the project B and C. 
So I added an entry to deployment assembly as : source - maven And dependencies deploy - web-inf/lib.
Tomcat comes up and my webapp for project A comes up.

This however breaks the eclipse build - upon build eclipse complains: 
**"Invalid classpath publish export Project entries not supported"**

This I see is because, under build path, there is new entry added to web-inf/lib to publish/export under maven-dependencies. Removing that removes maven entry from the deployment assembly as well.

The only workaround is that in the deployment assembly I specify the `web-inf/lib` under target generated by maven but that causes stale copies of project B and C to be picked up.

*Why I need this setting is because when I make changes to project B and C in Eclipse and build them in Eclipse I want to see the changes when I am debugging project A. I don't want to run maven builds on B and C again since its time consuming.*

Any help is much appreciated.

I did try including the `MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER` but that is always empty and when tomcat runs it cannot find the necessary libraries. (BTW what vale is the `MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTATINER` set to?)

This is on Eclipse Indigo Mac OSX.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to help but the text is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that searches for this, it seems that you can also manually add the following to the .classpath file

```
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/B"/>
```

Answer (score 37):

You need to add the relevant project/s to your Deployment Assembly.

Right Click Project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add

Comment: I agree that this solves the solution of the posted error, but it doesn't resolve the accompanying error for me, since the project is still being pulled in from Ivy as well.  ("The project contains another dependency with the same archive name.")

Comment: i also faced this issue today, however my deployment assembly has those sub projects/modules included. To resolve this first i removed all sub projects/modules and again added them in deployment assembly.

Comment: I'm just wondering why in all the other dozens of projects I have this has never been an issue, and THIS is the correct solution.

Answer (score 7):

I solved just doing this:

right click on my eclipse project-> Maven -> Update Project Configuration...

Comment: Update project configuration actually removes the warning... but also removes the project entries from the deployment descriptor :(

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out ..but not completely...

So I added **maven dependency** in the deployment assembly as I mentioned earlier.

```
Maven dependency -> WEB-INF/lib
```

AND additionally added **project B** and **C** as well :

```
B -> WEB-INF/lib and C->WEB-INF/lib
```

Somehow this way B and C are not added to the publish/export in the java build path. I don't know how eclipse knows to not export B and C from maven repo but to export it from project B and C itself.

Anyways thats for some other day..
for now i m happy :)

Answer (score 1):

By including Maven Dependencies, you are including dependencies for project B and project C. It turns out, you also have to include project B and C manually.

The exact fix which works is. 
project A -> properties -> Deployment Assembly

Click Add and then Project. Select B and C. Problem will get fixed after rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but I believe none of these answers correctly fix the problem. Instead they workaround m2eclipse (which should manage classpaths and deployment assembly for you). For me, the problem that I was using m2eclipse without m2eclipse-wtp (a separate plugin).

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193186/how-can-i-add-a-classpath-entry-as-a-publish-export-dependency-in-an-eclipse-dyn) for the plug-in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the relevant projects / or maven java build path entry if using maven to your Deployment assembly (project -> properties -> deployment Assembly)

Then checks if theses relevant project are Facets compatible. (project -> Project Facets)

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you have multiple entries of same jar in you class path. So you need to check your classpath and remove duplicate entries.